# ASP.NET MVC4 compile error on page after VS 2013 update 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

After upgrading my laptop from VS2012 to VS2013 and applying the VS2013 Update 4, and fixing the 4.000 to 4.001 System.Web.Mvc problem with nuGet, my MVC 4 web application builds, but in running it, I get a compile error on the front page:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'SubMenuItem' and no extension method 'SubMenuItem' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Source Error:

```
Line 3:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
Line 4:      <%= this.S("JTLanguage") %> - <%= this.S(Model.SubMenuItem) %>
Line 5:  </asp:Content>
```

However, this does work on my other development machine with the same set up.  One difference in behavior is that if I right-click "Model" in the source and select "Go to definition", on the laptop it takes me to the non-generic form of ViewPage, whereas on my development machine, it takes me to the generic version.  Here the page source first line:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TextViewData>" %>
```

Any ideas on how to figure out what is wrong?

Thanks.

-John

Comment: Please help, as it broke my VS2012 too, so I'm dead in the water.

Comment: Is there a log somewhere that might have useful information?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from MVC 4.0.0.1 to 5.2.2.0 seems to have fixed it.  I initially resisted upgrading as I thought it would require lots of changes to my 100's of views, but apparently not.  See https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2